# How to create vertical Bullet Graphs with PSTricks?

Tags: graphics, pgfplots, pstricks, wolfram-mathematica

I was looking for a package to create bullet gauge graphs, but I couldn't find any. A good person in this forum show me how he would make it in TikZ, with a little options.

I was waiting any moths but no package appear to make this fantastic kind of graphs with LATEX, so...

A bullet graph looks like this:
[image]

and an sample description/specification can be found [here](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/misc/Bullet_Graph_Design_Spec.pdf)

It is available in Mathematica 9 ([see here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/gauges/bullet-gauges.html)), with multiple details (but only in horizontal, it´s a pity!! vertical is very usefull )

***How you would create this kind of graphs (preferent in vertical) in a easy way with PSTricks in `LaTeX` (like Matehmatica 9 or similar)?***

I hope that a package to do this kind of graphics appear!

You can see the [available multiple options on horizontal bullets in Mathematica v.9](http://imageshack.us/a/img46/4341/3qw6.png) I´m only interested in the options of the simple graphs that you can see in the first little image. At most, any color changes.

Comment: Each vertical graph has 5 values to plot, correct?

Comment: @Herbert , Yes. In the examples, yes, but thera are many other options. But it´s enough for my answer, or to starting

Comment: @Mika I found your question interesting and I started to write a prototype for this feature in `pgfplots`. Would you like to become an early adopter and provide feedback/experiment with the prototype?

Comment: @christian-feuersanger Yes, of course!! Good News your comment. email me when you want, but my latex level is low, and my english... is... as you can view.  My email is mika2ikeATgmailDOTcom